# Hibernate Search with Apache Lucene

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I have a problems with my hibernate search.

I already included the jar file needed however, I don't know how to call the hibernate search annotation and if I needed to create another XML file for the hibernate search.

And also, how can I use this Hibernate Search, what are the cons and pros of this plugins and can you give me any reference like a tutorials on how can I use this. BTW, I'm also using Apache Lucene. It seems that both of this need to be present on my workstation to be able to use the Hibernate Search. I've looked up in Mr.G(google) but can't find a good tutorials that I can truly understand. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add properties in you **hibernate.cfg.xml** file for **hibernate.search.default.directory_provider** and **hibernate.search.default.indexBase**
You can refer to [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html_single/#d0e146) which gives you idea...

Comment: Thanks for the reply I already tried the code but it seems that the Indexed and DocumentId annotation doesn't recognized by the application, Anyway are these fixed values or should I change something in the said code. Sori newbie to hibernate :D

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I just forgot the hibernate-search jar the main jar of the hibernate-search my mistake :)